# How to move the resized image during file upload

Tags: php

I wish to resize the uploaded image to width: 750 and height: 930 pixels.
Here is the php:

```
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["cert"]["name"]);
if (strtolower($imageFileType) == 'jpg' ){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["cert"]["tmp_name"]);
    $wd = $check[0];
    $ht = $check[1];
    $wd_n = 750;
    $ht_n = 930;
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["cert"]["tmp_name"]);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($wd_n, $ht_n);
    imagesavealpha($src, true);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $wd_n, $ht_n, $wd, $ht);
}
```

Now, I wish to move this file to the upload folder. Without resizing, I could do it this way:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cert"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

How do I move the newly resized file to the upload folder?

Comment: If you have your new resized file, why don't you save this to your var and move it? The function for this would be `rename`.

Comment: Patrick, How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **imagejpeg** function

```
$path = <Path to directory + filename>
imagejpeg($dst, $path);
```

> $dst should be an image resource which is in you case.

Answer (score 0):

Would you care to try it like this:

```
<?php
    $target_dir     = "upload/";
    $target_file    = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["cert"]["name"]);

    if (strtolower($imageFileType) == 'jpg' ){
        $check  = getimagesize($_FILES["cert"]["tmp_name"]);

        // SAVE THE ORIGINAL, UPLOADED IMAGE TO DISK
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cert"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

        $wd     = $check[0];
        $ht     = $check[1];
        $wd_n   = 750;
        $ht_n   = 930;

        // GET THAT ORIGINAL IMAGE & PROCESS IT
        $src    = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);
        $dst    = imagecreatetruecolor($wd_n, $ht_n);

        imagesavealpha($src, true);
        imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $wd_n, $ht_n, $wd, $ht);

        // NOW; OVERRIDE THE ORIGINAL AND SAVE THE RESIZED VERSION...
        imagejpeg($dst, $target_file, 100);

        // OR SAVE IT TO A NEW LOCATION...
        $newLocation = str_replace("upload/", "upload/resized/", $target_file);
        imagejpeg($dst, $newLocation, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Unless this line  ->  imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $wd_n, $ht_n, $wd, $ht);     is added, only black images are produced.

Answer (score 0):

After your `$dst`, you can do it with imagejpeg.

```
imagejpeg($dst, "newPath/image.png");
```

Cheers.